# Change event triggered before click in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click a checkbox input in chrome the click event is triggered then the change event but in IE it's the other way around.

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4181/) on chrome, FF and IE.

```
        $("#checkbox").on('click',
        function () {
            console.log("click");
        }            
    );

    $("#checkbox").on('change',
        function () {
            console.log("change");
        }            
    );
```

My question is what to do to have IE to behave the same way as chrome and FF.

Comment: my question is why do you need both? In case of `checkboxes`/`radio`, `change` works when a different option is checked/unchecked. `Click` happens when you simply click on checkbox/radio. No real need for both

Comment: Perhaps change 'click' to 'mousedown' or 'mouseup'

Comment: tested in IE 8 and it is fine , what IE version do u use?

Comment: @MohammedElhag I use Edge

Comment: @RachidOussanaa Basically Edge is not a sort of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct way of the order of events, the click event should fire the last in order to be able to cancel it when the client has changed his mind.
The mouseup event fires before the click is completed so you could use the mouseup event to equalize between browsers.

```js
checkbox.onchange = function () {
                console.log("change");
            }

checkbox.onmouseup = function () {
                console.log("click");
            }
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" >​
```

Comment: Remember that you can `check` a checkbox with keyboard and in this case, the `click` event will be fired, but `mousedown` and `mouseup` events never will be fired.